Help with math in Kakegurui chapter 3
In Kakegurui manga chapter 3, Mary lost to Nishinotouin in the game of life or death and owed her debt totalling 4960万円. I am confused how does one obtain this number. For some reason, my math is not mathing .
So before Mary decided to bet all her remaining 32 chips into the final round, Mary had 32 chips remaining while Nishinotouin had 168 chips remaining. So the chip difference between two players was 136. When Mary lost the final round, her chip count became 32-180=-148 while Nishinotouin gained 180+168=348 chips. Their chip difference is now 348-(-148)=496. Since each chip worth 一万円, Mary owes her 4960万円?
Is there anything wrong with my calculations so far?
Oh wait, I think I just answered my own question...
